# Installing csv package in pycharm 3.6

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

i use windows and pycharm 3.6
and for some reason i can't import the csv package to my code.
it just goes gray
tried to use pip to install, didn't work.
if someone can help or otherwise recommend a different package that does the same thing, it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you run the program?

Comment: Recommending another package wouldn't help if you have troubles installing this one with pip

Comment: The [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module is a part of the [Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/) so there's nothing to install. When you import it in your code it should go gray until used, that's how PyCharm distinguishes between used and unused modules by default.

Comment: got it. tried to use the module and it suddenly recognize it.

Answer (score 3):

Unless `csv` has a red underline, the grey foreground color simply means you haven't used that module in your project yet. If you mouse over it, it will indicate `Unused import statement more...`

Comment: @Talis (if) this is the correct answer, please mark it as such.